# Cannot delete stubborn path in Windows 10, with files that cannot be found

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When deleting a folder in File Explorer, then I get this error:

> Could not find this item
> This is no longer located in D:\mypath... Verify the item's location and try again.

I can locate the file inside the folder (way down in the path tree) and see there is a file entry for it, but I cannot do anything with the file and I just want to delete it.

I have of course tried the usual stuff like rebooting my computer, run a command prompt as admin and deleting the folder recursively, tried booting in *Safe Mode* and also tried a couple of dedicated programs, but no matter what then I just cannot delete those files!

I have a lot of directories where I need to do this (a backup that seems to have run crazy), so I cannot do it manually - it needs to be done in bulk.

Are there any good ideas? :-)

[image]

**### UPDATE - A WORKING SOLUTION ###**

As mentioned by @johns comment then the [MajorGeeks Unlocker Portable 1.92](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlocker_portable.html) seems to be able to do the trick and the path and files inside gets deleted.

However it is a cumbersome process, as it only take *one* path per application launch, and as I need to do this on ~200 folders, then it will be a long manual process :-/

If anyone knows a better idea, then I would still like to know this but at least it is now possible for me to do this :-) Thanks @john.

Comment: Use Unlocker 1.92 (Majorgeeks) to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you emptied the *Recycle Bin*?
- Have you [checked if the file system is damaged](http://woshub.com/view-check-disk-chkdsk-results-in-windows-10/)?
- You state, "I can locate the file inside the folder (way down in the path tree)."

  - Is that a valid file, i.e., can you open it and view its contents?
  - [Windows has a default limit on the length of the filename & full path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry). Since the file is "way down in the path", you might need to [make Windows accept path\filename greater than 260 characters](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/) to access the file, or you might need to refer to the path by an alias as an [*Environment Variable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10).

Comment: I have emptied (1) Recycle Bin and (2) system is not bad as it is consequently the same folders/files in my backup tree that gives me problems and (3) I cannot read the files at all and (4) I cannot do this bulk.

Comment: @Beauvais, if you cannot open the file, it might not be there, or the path is too long. In the second case,  by changing the *global* Windows limit on file-path length, it wiould affect access to *all* files, whether by script or Explorer.

Comment: The path (including filename) is "only" 172 characters in length, so it is not that - also I did modify my Windows 10 Pro to allow for more than 260 characters, but still it cannot delete/read the file - but the application "Unlocker" can at least delete it, so for now this is my solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat late answer. The `rd` command did the trick for me.

```
rd /s "\?\C:\Users\admin\This_Folder_Is_Not_Getting_Deleted
```

This [reference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-solve-item-not-found-windows-error-deleting-file-folder/) could be helpful.